# Multiple libraries Android Studio project setup

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to understand how I should approach the following Android Studio Project setup:

```
|- Android Studio Project
|
|--- app
|     |
|     |- java
|     |- tests
|     |- resources
|
|
|--- core
|     |
|     |- java
|     |- tests
|     |- resources
.
.
.
|--- n-th library
```

As you can see i'd like a project which is composed of several Android libraries modules and, while building the **Android Studio project**, I'd like those modules to compile and create a single Android Application.

I've been searching for a solution, but I couldn't find one or, even if I did, I didn't understand it properly.

I know that there will be need to create multiple *build.gradle* files and one *settings.gradle* file, but I don't know what should I write in them.

What would be the best approach to handle this setup?